# Problem with console source in google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, console

I have faced a problem for a long time in the chrome browser, the point is that when I open the console in the chrome browser and open the "**Sources**" item, my project folder is not displayed now in more detail

I am developing a React application and I often need to insert debuggers to check something when I run the application in the Microsoft Edge browser everything works well.

[image]

Please now pay attention to what is happening in the google chrome browser

[image]

What could be the problem?